# Python3 AttributeError I don't understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

The code at the bottom generates the following traceback in my program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                         │
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request                                          │
    rv = self.dispatch_request()                                                                                                           │
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request                                               │
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)                                                                             │
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 325, in wrapper                                                │
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                       │
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 87, in view                                                           │
    self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)                                                                                    │
  File "/etc/changes/api/__init__.py", line 22, in __init__                                                                                │
    self.request_event = RequestEvent(request.environ)                                                                                     │
  File "/etc/changes/event/request_event.py", line 11, in __init__                                                                         │
    super(RequestEvent, self).__init__(event_data)                                                                                         │
  File "/etc/changes/event/__init__.py", line 14, in __init__                                                                              │
    self._load_json_object(event_data)                                                                                                     │
  File "/etc/changes/event/request_event.py", line 19, in _load_json_object                                                                │
    self.client_cert = self._get_certification_details().get('client_serial', None)                                                        │
  File "/etc/changes/event/request_event.py", line 23, in _get_certification_details                                                       │
    CLIENT_VERIFY = self.request_environment.get('CLIENT_VERIFY', None)                                                                    │
AttributeError: 'RequestEvent' object has no attribute 'request_environment'
```

I don't understand why, since the attribute is clearly made before the method. Any clue with which you can help me out? Some of the code has been removed for clarity.

```
from event import Event
from manager.manager_factory import ManagerFactory

class RequestEvent(Event):


    def __init__(self, request_environment, event_data={}):
        super(RequestEvent, self).__init__(event_data)
        self.request_environment = request_environment
        self.certification_details = self._get_certification_details()

    def _load_json_object(self,json_obj):
        super()._load_json_object(json_obj)
        self.type = 'request'
        self.trigger_invocation = json_obj.get('trigger_invocation', False)
        self.client_cert = self._get_certification_details().get('client_serial', None)
        self.tenant = ManagerFactory().authentication_manager

    def _get_certification_details(self):
        CLIENT_VERIFY = self.request_environment.get('CLIENT_VERIFY', None)
                   client_certificate_details = {}
        client_certificate_details['client_verify'] = CLIENT_VERIFY
        return client_certificate_details
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the trace-back carefully.

You have a recursive definition there. The super `__init__` is calling the `_load_json_object` method of the subclass. Which, in turn, is calling the `_get_vertification_details` method. All this is happening before you defined the `request_environment` attribute.